# error when trying to execute exe from Runtime object in java

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec

I am running windows 7 and have an exe file I am trying to run using the following command in Java:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\PATH\\TO\\DIR");
String[] cmdArray = {"file.exe"};

if(dir.exists()){
    for(String s : dir.list()){
        if(s.equals(cmdArray[0]))
            System.out.println("File exists!");
    }
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null,dir);
```

The exec(...) command, however, gives me this error:

```
Cannot run program "file.exe" (in directory "C:\PATH\TO\DIR"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The above code does print out "File Exists!" so the file is there and Java knows it is there.  I dont know how this is possible.

Also, I need to use Runtime.getRuntime().exex(...).  This call is actually inside another method that I am not suppose to change so alternative solutions will not work for me.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I ran the file in a cmd window without admin privileges and got the following message:

```
Error in Opening Configuration File in Read Mode
```

So I assume I have permission issues.  How would I change the permissions in order for me to be able to run it?

EDIT2:

I tried changing cmdArray to this:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"C:\\PATH\\TO\\DIR\\file.exe"};
```

and it worked like a charm.  One question though.  Why did this work but not the other way?  I assumed that Runtime.exec() ran at a high level like so in a cmd wibndow:

```
pushd dir
cmdArray[0] cmdArray[1] cmdArray[2] ... cmdArray[length - 1]
popd dir
```

Is this the wrong assumption?

Comment: Are you sure that your PATH contains '.'?

Comment: FYI ! Runtime.getRuntime().exec(**cmdarray**,null,dir); is not same as **cmdArray** defined in the beginning.

Comment: @NoobUnChained oh woops! that was a typo.  Was correct in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, You  will need to include your directory to your [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). You may take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741175/set-windows-path-environment-variable-at-runtime-in-java) and [this tutorial](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You are having the permission issue in the C drive.Check by executing `"file.exe"` manually in the C drive.Better solution will be to keep `"file.exe"` in some location other than C drive and execute from there.

Comment: I can execute the file through a cmd prompt with no permission issues

Comment: Right now the file is in the C drive and I have hard coded the path for test purposes.  The file should reside anywhere the user has it installed so I need it to work on the C drive if that is really the case.

Comment: But it won't work, if the user has permission issues with that drive!

Comment: @NoobUnChained ok, I think the cmd window I was using had admin rights.  I opened up a brand new cmd window and ran the command and got this: "Error in Opening Configuration File in Read Mode".  So I assume it is a permission issue.  How would I fix a permission issue then?

Comment: System administrator should give permission to that particular user account for that file.

Comment: @NoobUnChained So, is it not a permission issue?  I guess I am a little confused.  If it was a permission issue, shouldnt java tell me it is one instead of saying it cant find the file?

Comment: @NoobUnChained so, this is not a permission issue but for some reason, Java cannot actually find the file.  I do not know why but if I give the absolute path of the executable as my cmdArray, it works.  I dont know why this is.

Comment: @user972276 : just keep the file in other drive , try to execute , and see what happens , mean while , in your c drive , go to the file.exe , open its property , remove read only option and execute again