# Shell Script to add Appium path on mac

Tags: java, macos, shell

Is there any possible way to use a shell script to add adb path and apppium path on mac? or Is there a java code to set path on mac?

I have seen a question related to this(here [set windows PATH environment variable at runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741175/set-windows-path-environment-variable-at-runtime-in-java)) but it's for windows. someone can help me to work on mac

I am using this code but still no improvement. I can set windows environment variable not mac.

```
public static void testProcessBuilder(String path) throws IOException {
        //export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3
        //export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
        String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "export "+"JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home"};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        String line;
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        r.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "export "+"JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home"};
```

replace the above line to this line

`String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c","-l" "echo \"export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)\" >> ~/.bash_profile;source ~/.bash_profile"};`